# Incompatible types. Found: 'android.view.View', required: 'com.example.luckandchance.TextView'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to display text in textview but this error shows:

> Incompatible types. Found: 'android.view.View', required:
> 'com.example.luckandchance.TextView'

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.luckandchance;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import com.example.luckandchance.databinding.ActivityCoinTossBinding;

public class CoinToss extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView textView4;
private Button button3;

    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityCoinTossBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_coin_toss);

        textView4 = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably created a class with the automatic solution when the IDE suggested it.

Add these imports:

```
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

And delete the classes that you created.